# Как использовать chrome веб-инспектор для просмотра кода наведения на элемент? (псевдокласс hover)

Tags: html, css

Как использовать chrome веб-инспектор для просмотра кода наведения?

Comment: наведение на элемент :hover

Answer (score 3):

К примеру *(если я кончено правильно понял, что Вам нужно)*.

Открываем <kbd>ctrl + shift + i</kbd>. 
Выбираем нужный элемент.

Во вкладке `Styles` есть статическая строчка `Filter`, выбираем **`:hov`** и снова выбираем `:hover`.

Таким образом ниже появятся нужный код с `:hover`...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и каждый раз нужно ставить эти галки?

Comment: Зависит уже что Вам там нужно.. Возможно да.

Comment: посмотреть hover любого элемента, если он есть в css

Comment: @StepanIvanov, вот нашел что-то подобное https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools